# How can I download/upload images in a REST API?

Tags: php, image, api, codeigniter, rest

I'm about to code my first API for my codeigniter application (Using the [popular REST library](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/)), but I couldn't find a way to let users upload and download my application's images through the API. How is it usually done in API's?

I appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API uploads or downloads are done the same way whether you have a web application or a web service. You must use a `multipart/form-data` in a POST request for uploads, and send the proper response headers in downloads. In short, the [PHP manual on file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) and say, [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) for downloads, still applies for APIs.

Comment: This is really impotent. Could you please give us an example code.